# How would I change this code to have a 5 x 4 grid?

Tags: javascript

So how do I get the code to be a 5 x 4 grid like below.
I;m currently getting a 5 x 5 grid and undefined.

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

Credit to julien.giband for the help with the code.

```
  //Grid size: result will be n*n cells
const GRID_SIZE = 5;
const grid = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];
// Ship Locations
const shipLocations = ["3", "9", "15"];
let guess; //Entered value
let count = 0; //counter for rounds
do { //We'll loop indefintely until the user clicks cancel on prompt

  //Construct prompt using string template (multiline)
  const prpt = `Round #${++count}
${printGrid()}
Enter a Number Between 0-19`;
  guess = prompt(prpt);
  if (!guess && guess !== 0)
    break; //Stop when cancel was clicked
  
  const hit = shipLocations.indexOf(guess) >= 0;
  console.log(`At round ${count}, cell ${guess} is a ${hit ? 'hit': 'miss'}`);
  grid[guess] = hit ? '1' : 'X';
} while (guess || guess === 0); //Must have an exit condition

/** Pretty-print the grid **/
function printGrid() {
  let res = "";
  for (let r = 0; r < GRID_SIZE; r++) {
    let srow = "";
    for (let c = 0; c < GRID_SIZE; c++) {
      srow += " " + grid[r * GRID_SIZE + c];
    }
    res += srow.substr(1) + '\n';
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: instead of  `GRID_SIZE ` you should use 2 variables `GRID_ROW_SIZE` and `GRID_COLUMN_SIZE` and replace those in your for loop

Comment: Both `for` loops are using `GRID_SIZE` iterations, you need to use 5 and 4 instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your "printGrid" you are looping to 5 (GRID_SIZE) for both rows (r) and columns (c).  You will need different size values for the rows and columns if you want a 5x4 grid:

```js
ROW_GRID_SIZE=4;
COL_GRID_SIZE=5;
```

and change your loops:

```js
  for (let r = 0; r < ROW_GRID_SIZE; r++) {
    let srow = "";
    for (let c = 0; c < COL_GRID_SIZE; c++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating a grid of any N * N, I have created a dynamic array creating function.

```js
function genArray(N) {
  return Array.from(Array(N), (_, i) => "0")
}
function createDynamicGrid(row, column) {
  const rows = genArray(row)
  return rows.map((i) => genArray(column))
} 

console.log(createDynamicGrid(2,2))
```